# Where did KDE's Power Management go?

Tags: kde, power-management

Two installations of the same system on the same machine (different SSD's).  One has Power Management, the other doesn't.  The one that doesn't did briefly, and then lost it.  How can I get it back?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another case of knowing the ***exact*** search terms to get the answer.  Not just any terms will do.  So you almost have to know the answer already, before you can get the answer.

Anyway, KDE's power manager is called "Power Devil" - *that's* what took forever to find - and then googling that and seeing the package pages suggested that I could just install that.  And sure enough, `sudo apt install powerdevil` did the trick.  I still don't know what happened to have it missing to start with, since it's supposed to come free with everything else and just be there.  Mine just wasn't.

After that command, I had the menu entry immediately, with a semi-transparent note over the settings that said it wasn't running, then after a reboot, it works!  I can finally watch a movie without wiggling the mouse every 10 minutes to keep the screen from dying.