# x11vnc causes KDE Plasma to reset when the screen is off

Tags: kde, remote-desktop, vnc, plasma

- When the screen is on, it works perfectly.
- When the screen is off - via the timeout that I set in the power settings, or manually - the VNC client appears to no longer receive updates.
- When I wiggle the mouse on the VNC server machine to turn the screen back on, the client immediately gets an update, and I get this notification from KDE on the server:
  [image]

It used to be that I could VNC into this machine and use it remotely as usual, with the screen staying off.  I kinda liked that!  But now I have to keep the screen on, and if I have a timeout in the power settings, it kinda kills my VNC session when that timeout happens.

Can I get that functionality back?  Screen already off, VNC into it, and run a VNC session normally without the screen turning on?

It's possible that I'm remembering a different VNC server.  Maybe one that comes with KDE by default?  [I did have to manually install the power manager, which is also supposed to be there by default but wasn't.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1479919/321777)

---

I have this in login.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash



# Settle down

sleep 10



# Touchscreen on correct monitor only

xinput map-to-output "Wacom ISDv4 4001 Finger touch" eDP-1-1



# VNC Server

xrandr --listactivemonitors | grep eDP-1-1          \
| awk -- '{ gsub(/\/[0-9]+/,"",$3) ; print $3 }'    \
| while read GEOMETRY
do
    x11vnc -clip $GEOMETRY -auth /path/to/.Xauthority -forever -loop10 -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /path/to/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared &
done



# Audio Defaults (from pactl get-default-[sink|source])

pactl   set-default-sink    "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
pactl   set-default-source   "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
```

And it's called from here:
[image]

[image]
Ubuntu Studio 22.04
**KDE Plasma Version:** 5.24.7
**KDE Frameworks Version:** 5.92.0
**Qt Version:** 5.15.3
**Kernel Version:** 5.15.0-78-lowlatency (64-bit)
**Graphics Platform:** X11